# sort only particular rows sql server

Tags: linq, sql-server-2008, sql-order-by

I have six rows like

```
col1     col2
--------------
Apple    120
XApple   140 
Banana   130
Xbanana  150
Car      110
XCar     160
```

I would like to sort these rows on col2 but leave the rows with 'X' alone.

so after sorting the rows should be like

```
col1     col2
--------------
Car      110
Apple    120
Banana   130
XCar     160
XApple   140
Xbanana  150
```

meaning, the rows with car apple and banana should be sorted but the rows with xcar, xapple and xbanana should be left alone and just be appended at the end.
I tried

```
select * 
from table
where col1 not like 'X%' order by col2
union
select * 
from table
where symbol like 'X%'
```

but sql server doesn't allow that. Could anybody point me to the right direction or tell me that this is not possible?

PS: any LINQ solution will also be fine.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no order without an explicit `ORDER BY` clause.  While you can use `UNION` to group the rows, you cannot guarantee that the order of the unordered rows is stable.  See [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/conor_cunningham_msft/archive/2008/08/27/no-seatbelt-expecting-order-without-order-by.aspx).

The following will split the list into two groups of rows, but each will be sorted by `Col1`:

```
select Col1, Col2
  from (
    select Col1, Col2, 1 as PleaseSort
      from MyTable
      where Col1 not like 'X%'
    union
    select Col1, Col2, 0
      from MyTable
      where Col1 like 'X%' ) as PlaceHolder
  order by PleaseSort desc, Col1
```

Comment: @user1 - I always forget that silly alias.  Updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Order by whether the first character of col1 is 'X' or not, and then by col2.

Example:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
ORDER BY CASE WHEN col1 LIKE 'X%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,col2
```

Although, this doesn't leave the LIKE 'X%' rows unordered, neither did your example.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the sort of upper limit for how many x rows you'll get then you could do something like....

```
select * from (select top 5000 col1 from #tmp order by col1) a
union
select col1 from #tmp
```

Comment: as far as I know, UNION typically works like a DISTINCT and performs a scan of previous values and appends only new rows (UNION ALL would append all rows) so your ORDER _should_ be preserved - but test!